# SELECT userinformation where userid is in the most rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains the same userid multiple times.

I would like to return the picture of 9 users that have the most rows with their userid in it.

How can I select the user with the most rows and the ones following (from most to least)?

It's probably something easy but I can't find an answer.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM beoordelingen,users WHERE beoordelingen.userid=users.userid
GROUP BY beoordelingen.userid LIMIT 9 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ("The query could not be completed. try again");

$cols=3;
    echo "<table width='150' border='0' cellpadding='0'>";  // The container table with $cols columns
do{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){   // All the rows will have $cols columns even if
                                // the records are less than $cols
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row){
            echo"<td> 
            <table width='150' border='0' cellpadding='0'>
            ";
    if ($row["userimage"] == '') {
            echo "<a href='user.php? id=" . $row['userid'] . "'</a><img src='Images/users/nopicture.png' alt='nopicture'
            class='userimage-tooltip-large' title='".$row['username']."''>";
    } else {
            echo "<a href='user.php? id=" . $row['userid'] . "'</a><img src='Images/users/".$row['userimage']."'
            class='userimage-tooltip-large' title='".$row['username']."''>";
    }
            echo"</table>
            </td>";
    } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; //If there are no more records at the end, add a blank column

    }
    }
    } while($row);
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a count of the rows with the userid, order by that descending and then use the limit:-

```
SELECT users.userimage, 
        users.userid,
        users.username,
        COUNT(*) AS userid_count
FROM beoordelingen
INNER JOIN users 
ON beoordelingen.userid=users.userid
GROUP BY beoordelingen.userid 
ORDER BY userid_count DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Note that which values you get of the columns other than the userid is not defined. If you want the values from a particular row then this is a bit more complicated and you need to define which one.

Comment: THANK YOU Kickstart! That works wonderful. I'm very grateful. I will mark your answer as soon as they let me :-)